# logout a user when the user faces unusual thing

Tags: php, authentication, redis, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

is there any way to logout a user in yii2 advanced, when the user faces unusual thing(like shut down his/her computer when the user works with his/her account).
default of yii2:when you are login and your computer goes into shut down,when you start up for another time and go to your account ,you are in login state but your session ID will change.
i want to logout the user or at least the session id never change.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to disable `enableAutoLogin` parameter for User class, so that when user closes browser or shutdowns/restarts a computer, he will have to enter login data again.

This kind of behavior is often used in banking systems (at least in my country) for security reasons.

If that is what you are looking for, then this setting can be configured in `frontend/config/main.php` file

```
'components' => [
    ..
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        ..
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

If a user restarts their computer, the browser session cookies that are there will remain in place until they expire or the user chooses to delete them/clear data from their browser cache. By definition, if the user remains logged in, their session *has* been preserved. This has nothing to do with whether a client computer has been restarted or any other change of state on a client machine - your website is agnostic to this, i.e. it does not have any mechanism to know of this particular change in state and neither should it care.

If you wish to logout a user programatically, you can use this code for the native [Yii2 user application component](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html) in your controller:

`Yii::$app->user->logout();`